# Python - Folder of long .txt files, search through each .txt file for various substrings, append to list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, directory

So I have a directory of .txt files

~~~
c:\users\Admin\Documents\Exm
~~~

Each .txt file is extensive and I need to find certain sub-strings contained in each file ('Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange', etc).

My understanding is that I need a [for loop] to iterate through the directory AND another [for loop] to iterate through each .txt file.

~~~

OBJECTIVE: a list of the first sub-string found in each .txt file. So if 'apple' is found first in 1.txt and 'pear' is found first in 2.txt the list would like like the following:

['apple', 'pear',...,'n-th fruit']

~~~

This is what I have so far:

~~~

```
import glob
import os

names = os.listdir('c:\\users\Admin\Documents\Exm')
lst = []
lst_2 =[]

#Appends lst with all newly converted .txt Files (from .SIF files)
for name in names:
    if name.endswith(".txt"):
        lst.append(name)

#PROBLEM STARTS HERE - Intended to open each .txt file in directory 
for file in names:

    #Quick file verification (not each file is a .txt
    if file.endswith('.txt.'):

        #Opens a single .txt file in directory
        with open(os.path.join('c:\\users\Admin\Documents\Exm', file)) as f:

             #Iterates through each line in .txt file
             for line in f:

                 #Temporary String placeheader for further checking
                 content = f.readlines()

                 if content = 'Apple' :
                     lst_2.append('Apple')

                 elif content = 'Pear' :
                     lst_2.append('Pear')

                 elif content = 'Orange' :
                     lst_2.append('Orange')

                 else:
                     lst_2.append('Fruit not Found')

print(lst_2)
```

~~~

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Since you're using `readlines` you may need another for loop to iterate over each line in the file.

Comment: I am open to not using readlines if there is a more efficient way. 
~~~

Comment: Idk for sure if it's more efficient, but just using `read` will read the whole file in as one string, rather than a list of strings. If the files aren't very big, it may help simplify things.

Comment: It's probably easier to search for a substring over one long string, than it is through a list of strings. I'm going to try your recommendation, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i've splited the each line to yield words separated by spaces and process them one by one instead of whole line.
heres the difference:

```
names = os.listdir('c:\\users\Admin\Documents\Exm')
lst = []
lst_2 =[]

#Appends lst with all newly converted .txt Files (from .SIF files)
for name in names:
    if name.endswith(".txt"):
        lst.append(name)

#PROBLEM STARTS HERE - Intended to open each .txt file in directory 
for file in names:
    #Quick file verification (not each file is a .txt
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        #Opens a single .txt file in directory
        with open(os.path.join('c:\\users\Admin\Documents\Exm', file)) as f:

             #Iterates through each line in .txt file
             for line in f:

                 #Temporary String placeheader for further checking
                 c = line.split(' ') # split the line content by spaces
                 for content in c: # for each word in line

                     if content == 'Apple' :
                         lst_2.append('Apple')

                     elif content == 'Pear' :
                         lst_2.append('Pear')

                     elif content == 'Orange' :
                         lst_2.append('Orange')

                     #else:
                         #lst_2.append('Fruit Not Found')
  print(lst_2)
```

about your code as a whole, why not just use one loop like:

```
lst=[]
lst_2=[]
for f_name in os.listdir('path_here'):
    if f_name.endswith(".txt"):
        lst.append(f_name)# append the names
        with open(os.path.join('path_here', f_name)) as file:
            for line in file:
                pass #do the word search by line
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm relatively new to all of this so I don't yet have a grasp on good form; you are right it should be one loop! Your code does indeed work, but it raised cases which I previously was unaware of. The .txt files I am searching through have...unconventional format. That is, sometimes 'afs43rApplesad fsadf' will be the string: 'Apple' is present but it is not recognized. What I realize now is that I need a function to search each element in a list of strings for a substring which may be present. Do you have any further suggestions? Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: you can use `in` to check if a string is inside another string, like `'Apple' in 'afs43rApplesad fsadf'`, `'Apple' in content` instead of `content == 'Apple'`